# Can I run a query on an arbitrary subset of a table to speed up query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a program that reads a file and writes data about the file into a table. Something went wrong with the program and I have 215,728,403 rows where I only expect about 2-3 million. I'm trying to figure out the problem and I want to look at the table. I suspect there are a lot of duplicate entries but querying this table is taking a very long time (let run for 1 hour with no results with the following query):

```
select * from table ou
where (select count(*) from table inr
where inr.dieoffset = ou.dieoffset) > 1
```

Would I be able to run this on the first 10,000,000 rows without a performance hit and how would I achieve this?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the first 10,000,000 rows".  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `limit`:

```
select *
from ou
limit 1000
```

Without an `order by`, this should read an arbitrary set of rows, quickly.

Comment: Ahh ya, I just thought I can do this an select them into a table then use that table as a sample

Comment: @TreeWater . . . You can do that too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some index to speed up the queries?

To find doublons, you can use a group by:

```
SELECT   COUNT(*) AS nbr_doublon, champ1, champ2, champ3
FROM     table
GROUP BY champ1, champ2, champ3
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you want to do that on a subset:

```
SELECT   COUNT(*) AS nbr_doublon, champ1, champ2, champ3
FROM     (SELECT * from table limit 100000)
GROUP BY champ1, champ2, champ3
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: No index as all the columns can contain duplicate values. Ideally I would add some indexes / unique clauses soon but I'd like to figure out the source of these duplicates as I think there is a bug in my program